# Difference between Placemarks and Annotations

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

Not very well versed with iOS Development. I have a very stupid question to ask!! is there a difference between Placemarks and Annotations. Ive been through some Apple Developer documents. Somewhere it was mentioned Placemarks have areaOfInterest property. Im not sure if annotations have one too.

Apart from that how do Placemarks differ from Annotations??

Thanks in Advance!! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MKPlacemark class reference:

> A placemark is also an annotation and conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol, whose properties and methods include the placemark coordinate and other information. Because they are annotations, you can add them directly to the map view.

`MKPlacemark` inherits from `CLPlacemark`, which has property `areasOfInterest`.

A look at the class references for both classes and the protocol should clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Annotations offer a way to highlight specific coordinates on the map and provide additional information about them. You can use annotations to call out specific addresses, points of interest, and other types of destinations. When displayed on a map, annotations typically have some sort of image to identify their location and may also have a callout bubble providing information and links to more content.

For Placemarks See This Link

http://ioscreator.com/display-placemarks-with-mapkit/

Comment: Thanks for taking the pains to reply but this really doesnt answer the original question

Comment: I have only told the Link i think this link will be helpful to solve your issue